# "hello world" Java Error: Couldn't find it being resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, compiler-errors

This is shown in the console of MyEclipse when trying to run a simple "Hello world" program. Sort of surprised that noone has a solution yet.

I think this should be such a basic issue that should be addressed, but couldn't find it being resolved anywhere.

***Problem:***
I am getting the following error Message when trying to run a small Java program. I assume it might be a "setup error" or "compiler error" of my Eclipse but not sure. I cannot re-setup because I have enterprise Java being setup here. That took a boatload of time. So have to resolve without any re-installations and such.

In red it shows as:

```
Usage: java javassist.tools.reflect.Compiler
           (<class> [-m <metaobject>] [-c <class metaobject>])+
```

To make sure that it is not an issue of my program, I made a new class where I tried to print "Hello World".. and still I get the same error message where it did not display the output.

Comment: please show us the code of the class.

Comment: Just the basic "hello world" program outputs the same error..

Comment: yes show the program code

Comment: well..
class 

HelloWorldApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); //Display the string.
    }
}

Comment: Looks like a setup error.  Javassist.tools.reflect.Compiler is used to modify the bytecode of classes so they can be used for reflection. Either Eclipse is calling this class unnecessarily, or it needs to call it, but is doing so with the incorrect arguments.

Comment: Thanks @DavidChoweller for your input. Not sure what the course of action is to resolve it, hopefully someone can advice that. If you think it is a helpful question that benefits the beginners or the community, I will appreciate an upvote.

Comment: In your Eclipse project settings or preferences look for those related to a Javassist plugin, or perhaps preferences related to "builders" that may be automatically invoked when you try to run a Java program in Eclipse.

Comment: I tweaked some settings sounded along the same lines of what you mentioned(both for projects settings and eclipse settings) to see if it takes off the bug, apparently it doesn't. Not the ones I played with. If you have a specific setting that you can provide directions on, I can try that out. @DavidChoweller

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out myself. This is a Run configuration issue.
Right click your project --> Run As --> Run configuration --> Under the "main class" input box enter your fully qualified class name where your main() resides. Or the better way would be to click the "Search" button near to it and select the appropriate package.

Make sure it is running as a "Java Application" or under the correct "Server".

It should be resolved for the most part.

**Anyways it is a Run configuration issue.**